# no matches for kind "Kibana" in version "kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1"

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, amazon-eks

I'm trying to deploy kibana on eks but getting this error when I run this command kubectl apply -f kibana.yml

`error: unable to recognize "kibana.yml": no matches for kind "Kibana" in version "kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1"`

Config file:

```
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: core-staging
spec:
  version: 7.14.0
  count: 1
  config:
    elasticsearch.hosts:
      - <elasticsearch host>
    elasticsearch.username: <elasticsearch user>
    elasticsearch.password: <password>
```

Comment: Have you created CRDs that define resources in `kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1` api? Do they define resources of `kind: Kibana`?

Comment: @zerkms No I've not. Do I have to create CRD with kind: Kibana first in  kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1 api?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/ If you're using some controller to manage kibana application - they should provide you instructions on how to install/configure it.

Comment: I'm not using any controller for kibana.

Comment: Who will install it for you then?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to run this thing first:

```
kubectl create -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/2.6.1/crds.yaml
```

Reference:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-eck.html