# what is the kind and apiversion used to specify a kibana instance on kubernetes?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, yaml, kibana, kind

I have the following .yaml file:

```
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: quickstart
spec:
  version: 8.0.0
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: quickstart
```

when I try to create the instance using kubectl create -f , I get the error

```
error: unable to recognize: no matches for kind "Kibana" in version "kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1"
```

Comment: Hello @ashique, according to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68741236/no-matches-for-kind-kibana-in-version-kibana-k8s-elastic-co-v1) your problem may be connected with [CRD](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/#customresourcedefinitions).  Did you create one?

Answer (score 1):

How you have installed it? looks like you are missing the **CRD**

Try applying this once:

`kubectl apply -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/1.0.0/all-in-one.yaml`

You can check the list of API resources available :

`kubectl api-resources`